# How can I get information about type of a Go variable

Tags: variables, types, go, type-inference

Suppose I have the following code in Go:

```
foo, bar := someFunc(baz)
```

I would like to create a Vim function to check type of `foo` or `bar` when editing a file.

Is there any tool or reliable source of information for functions from Go's packages I could use or? As for the functions declared in the file I'm editing I was thinking about simply parsing all the functions declared in that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for something like [`godef`](https://godoc.org/github.com/rogpeppe/godef)

> If the -t flag is given, the type of the expression will also be
>   printed. The -a flag causes all the public members (fields and
>   methods) of the expression, and their location, to be printed also;
>   the -A flag prints private members too.

I know it is being used by various vim and emacs scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The [Go Oracle](https://golang.org/s/oracle-user-manual) does this and much more.

[`vim-go`](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go) is a complete vim setup for Go.
It includes integration with the previously mentioned [`godef`](https://godoc.org/github.com/rogpeppe/godef) (as :GoDef) and Go oracle (as :GoImplements, :GoCallees, :GoReferrers, etc) as well as other tools.